# Negation of A Quantifier

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$∃ ∀ ((¬ () \land((y<0)\Rightarrow P(y)))$

What is the negation of this expresion?

I try to solve with steps like that:
First I negated the easy part on the outside. Secondly used the equality of if. Third negated the first layer of parenthesis and then lastly negated the innner parenthesis.
then used De Morgan to negate inner parenthesıs.

$∀ ∃ ¬((¬ () \land ((y<0)\Rightarrow P(y)))$

$∀ ∃ ¬(( () \land (¬(y<0)\lor P(y)))$

$∀ ∃ ((¬ () \lor ¬(¬(y<0)\lor P(y)))$

$∀ ∃ ((¬ () \lor ((y<0)\land ¬P(y)))$

Comment: The second line should read $∀ ∃ ¬((¬ () \land (¬(y<0)\lor P(y)))$ so the final answer is $∀ ∃ (( () \lor ((y<0)\land ¬P(y)))$.

Comment: Thanks for checking.

Comment: You're welcome.